# How to parameterise the data connection in Tableau in AWS (cloudformation or otherwise)?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, tableau-api, amazon-quicksight

I have a simple web app UI (which stores certain dataset parameters (for simplicity, assuming they are all data tables in a single Redshift database, but the schema/table name can vary, and the Redshift is in AWS). Tableau is installed on an EC2 instance in the same AWS account.

I am trying to determine an automated way of passing 'parameters' as a data source (i.e. within the connection string inside Tableau on EC2/AWS) rather than manually creating data source connections and inputting the various customer requests.

The flow for the user would be say 50 users select various parameters on the UI (for simplicity suppose the parameters are stored as a JSON file in AWS) -> parameters are sent to Tableau and data sources created -> connection is established within Tableau without the customer 'seeing' anything in the back end -> customer is able to play with the data in Tableau and create tables and charts accordingly.

How may I do this at least through a batch job or cloud formation setup? A "hacky" solution is fine.

Bonus: if the above is doable in real-time across multiple users that would be awesome.

** I am open to using other dashboard UI tools which solve this problem e.g. QuickSight **

After installing Tableau on EC2 I am facing issues in finding an article/documentation of how to pass parameters into the connection string itself and/or even parameterise manually.

An example could be customer1 selects "public_schema.dataset_currentdata" and "public_scema.dataset_yesterday" and one customer selects "other_schema.dataser_currentdata" all of which exist in a single database.

3 data sources should be generated (one for each above) but only the data sources selected should be open to the customer that selected it i.e. customer2 should only see the connection for other_schema.dataset_currentdata.

One hack I was thinking is to spin up a cloud formation template with Tableau installed for a customer when they make a request, creating the connection accordingly, and when they are done then just delete the cloud formation template. I am mainly unsure how I would get the connection established though i.e. pass in the parameters. I am not sure spinning up 50 EC2's though is wise. :D

An issue I have seen so far is creating a manual extract limits the number of rows. Therefore I think I need a live connection per customer request. Hence I am trying to get around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a combination of a [basic embed](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_sample_basic_embed.htm) and applying [filters](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_concepts_filtering.htm).  This would load the Tableau workbook.  Then you would apply a filter based on whatever values your user selects from the JSON.

The final missing part is that you would use a parameter instead of a filter and pass those values to the database via [initial sql](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/connect_basic_initialsql.htm#parameters-in-an-initial-sql-statement).

Comment: Thanks I will give it a whizz and feedback. Any idea is this applies to one user/one workbook at a time? If 50+ users are doing this at the same time, I would need to spin up 50 EC2's each with Tableau installed? Finally is the embed etc real-time or batch i.e. customer makes the request --> how long before they can see it in Tableau.

Comment: That all depends on your implementation, how fast you can spin up (or allocate) resources, etc.  I suggest you check out this excellent blog [Tableau and Behold](https://tableauandbehold.com/embedding-tableau-server/).

Comment: Just to add, in general you should only need 1 Tableau Server.  It can be used to host 50+ different users.